Facebook Login OAuth Flow without SDK
When I use the connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js and call FB.login() I get a login/auth popup window. When someone logs in, the window closes, and the callback function supplied to FB.login is called with a response object. From that response object I pull out response.authResponse.accessToken and I can use that to verify user information by calling facebook. Great!
Now how do I do that without using the sdk.js?
I can manually open the popup and there is some documentation out in the wild on how to do that.
const appId = 'REDACTED';
const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('https://example.net/callback');
    
// Construct the Facebook login URL
const loginUrl = `https://www.facebook.com/v19.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=${appId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=token&scope=public_profile,email`;

// Open the Facebook login window
window.open(loginUrl, 'Facebook Login', 'width=600,height=400');

But now the flow is completely different! It uses a callback address and loads that address in the popup after login instead of closing. I don't want that. Somehow or other the SDK opens the window and sets up messaging between the parent and the popup. How do I recreate that?
The end goal is to :

Not have the js sdk loaded
Have the facebook popup close on login
Have the facebook popup call my own callback method and pass the token


You have to manage through postMessage API:
So when the user land on /callback page in the opened popup you can do:


window.opener.postMessage(dataParsedFromUrl, "*") // comunicate data to opener
// dataParsedFromUrl is derived from parameters that facebook append to your redirect url
window.close() //close the popup



So in your page you need to add the EventListener to get data in the moment that the popup comunicate the message:


const appId = 'REDACTED';
const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('https://example.net/callback');
    
// Construct the Facebook login URL
const loginUrl = `https://www.facebook.com/v19.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=${appId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=token&scope=public_profile,email`;

// Open the Facebook login window
window.open(loginUrl, 'Facebook Login', 'width=600,height=400');

window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
  console.log(e.data) // dataParsedFromUrl
})



